# URL rewrite with "303 see also" redirect using UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

is there a way to create a UrlRewriteFilter that redirects requests with a "303 see also" response code? From the documentation it seems that it supports only 301 and 302 redirects.

If it's not currently possible, what part of UrlRewriteFilter should I have a look at to get this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a patch was submitted back in 2012 for that.  If you're up to modifying your own copy of the code, look here:https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=124